# Looking for the perfect high availability with MySQL replication and concurrent inserts

Tags: mysql

I'm building a software that needs high availability, I want to use MySQL Master-Master row-based replication.

My only issue is I need to handle concurrent inserts on table with UNIQUE index. So my technique is to do SELECT and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so if an INSERT happens after SELECT I won't have duplicate key error.

The problem is this statement is unsafe for row-based and can break replication.

So what's a good high availability system for MySQL ?

Comment: You want the `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` settings. Setting them correctly will make one server create IDs like 1,3,5,7 and the other 2,4,6,8. Systems like Percona Cluster or Galera handle this automatically for you.

Comment: I'm not talking about the auto_inc but UNIQUE indexes, with lots of concurrent insert it can break replication cause same insert goes to both masters and when they try to replicate duplicate key error

Comment: Why would the same insert ever go to both masters?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because different clients try to create rows with the same unique key. E.g. two users trying to register with the same username.

Comment: @Barmar In real practice that's pretty unusual. If you're encountering it frequently you should use a cluster-aware synchronous multi-master system like Percona or Galera.